# add arrays returns the same answer JAVA AnsroidStudio

Tags: java, android

So I'm pretty new and I'm making a program that you can input 12 difderent numbers then you can add them but for some reason the answer is always 12 because the base value of the editText I put is 2 to not have an int string error anyway to fix this?

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //declaring variables

    final EditText number1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editNumber1);
    EditText number2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editNumber2);
    EditText number3 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editNumber3);
    EditText number4 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editNumber4);
    EditText number5 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editNumber5);
    EditText number6 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editNumber6);
    number1.setText("2");
    int a1 = Integer.parseInt(number1.getText().toString());
    number2.setText("2");
    int a2 = Integer.parseInt(number2.getText().toString());
    number3.setText("2");
    int a3 = Integer.parseInt(number3.getText().toString());
    number4.setText("2");
    int a4 = Integer.parseInt(number4.getText().toString());
    number5.setText("2");
    int a5 = Integer.parseInt(number5.getText().toString());
    number6.setText("2");
    int a6 = Integer.parseInt(number6.getText().toString());

    Button btnResult = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonSum);
    final TextView txtResult = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtResults);

    //declaring the arrays list
    int[] Array1 = {a1, a2, a3};
    int[] Array2 = {a4, a5, a6};
    final int sum = Array1[0] +Array1[1] + Array1[2] + Array2[0] + Array2[1] + Array2[2];


    btnResult.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,Integer.toString(sum), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the a1 to a6 lines with the arrays and the sum lines inside the onclicklistner event method  before the toast line

Comment: thanks alot man it worked but could you explain for me why did we do that?

Comment: **OnCreate** is only called once when the activity first load which will register the initial value of 2 on your a1 to a6 variables and in sequence Array1 , Array2 and the sum variables.
But the **onClicklistner** is called on each click which will execute all the block of code inside it so we should put the code that extracts the values from the editTextboxes inside it to grab the fresh values.